# Setting dotenv path outside of root directory is not working

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I want to set the path of dotenv config and it does not work.
My directory is

myproject/script/.env

myproject/web/src/config.js,

so I set dotenv path in config.js as following, which does not work.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config({ path: '../../scripts/.env'})
```

Is it not possible to set path outside of `web` directory? Because it worked when I put the `.env` file in `web` directory. The thing is I want to use another `.env` file which is in `script` directory and I can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relative path like that is relative to the current working directory (try logging that with `console.log(process.cwd())`), not relative to the location of the file you're in.

To make that path relative to your `config.js` you can do this instead:

```
dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../scripts/.env` })
```